# Material dialog in the middle

Tags: dialog, angular6

It is possible to set material dialog window automatically on the middle of the screen? When I opened dialog window, the window is in top-left corner. I noticed, that I can change position of the window manually with css class : .cdk-overlay-container like this :

```
.cdk-overlay-container {
    margin: 200px 0 0 0;
}
```

It is possible to make it automatically? Unfortunately, margin: auto does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The below should work if the cdk-overlay-container is 100% width and 100% height of the browser window.

```
.cdk-overlay-container {
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```